# encoding json with no quote around numerical values

Tags: json, perl

I have a perl code snippet

```
use JSON::XS;
$a = {"john" => "123", "mary" => "456"};
print encode_json($a),"\n";
```

The output is

```
{"john":"123","mary":"456"}
```

Wonder if there is an option to cause encode_json function (from JSON::XS module) to encode it so that the values (123,  456) are not surrounded by double-quote. i.e., like

```
{"john":123,"mary":456}
```

Unfortunately I can't change the hash in $a because it's passed to me from another function.  Wonder if there is any trick on encode_json().

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to preprocess the data yourself, prior to JSON serialization.

This solution uses [Data::Leaf::Walker](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Leaf::Walker) to traverse an arbitrary structure, converting strings to numbers.

```
use JSON;
use Data::Leaf::Walker;
use Scalar::Util qw();

my $a = {"john" => "123",
         "mary" => ["456","aa"],
         "fred" => "bb",
         "nested" => {"Q" => undef, "A" => 42},
         };

my $walker = Data::Leaf::Walker->new( $a );

while (my ( $key_path, $value ) = $walker->each ) {
    $walker->store($key_path, $value + 0)
        if Scalar::Util::looks_like_number $value;
};

print  to_json($a);
```

Output: `{"john":123,"nested":{"A":42,"Q":null},"mary":[456,"aa"],"fred":"bb"}`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `JSON::XS` directly, just `JSON` will already load `JSON::XS` if available.

A scalar in Perl is tagged whether it is a string or a number, and here you're providing strings. Remove the quotes from your numbers, and they should show up unquoted as `JSON` already does that automatically.

If you're reading strings (from say a database) then you can coerce the strings to numbers like this:

```perl
{ john => 0+$john, mary => 0+$mary }
```

**Update, here's a recursive replacement:**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use JSON;
use Modern::Perl;
use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number );

my $structure = {
    john => "123",
    mary => 456,
    deeper => {
        lucy => "35zz",
        names => [
            "john",
            "123",
            456,
        ],
    },
};

sub make_numbers_recursively {
    my ( $data ) = shift;

    if ( ref $data eq 'HASH' ) {

        # Replace hash values with recurisvely updated values
        map { $data->{ $_ } = make_numbers_recursively( $data->{ $_ } ) } keys %$data;

    } elsif ( ref $data eq 'ARRAY' ) {

        # Replace each array value with recursively processed result
        map { $_ = make_numbers_recursively( $_ ) } @$data;

    } else {

        $data += 0 if looks_like_number( $data );

    }

    return $data;
}

my $json = JSON->new->pretty;
say $json->encode( $structure );
make_numbers_recursively( $structure );
say $json->encode( $structure );
```

This outputs:

```
{
   "mary" : 456,
   "deeper" : {
      "names" : [
         "john",
         "123",
         456
      ],
      "lucy" : "35zz"
   },
   "john" : "123"
}

{
   "mary" : 456,
   "deeper" : {
      "names" : [
         "john",
         123,
         456
      ],
      "lucy" : "35zz"
   },
   "john" : 123
}
```

Beware that it modifies the structure in-place, so if you need the original data for anything you might want to `Clone` or `Data::Clone` it first.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The hash $a has hundreds of fields (all with numerical values), using the trick of adding "0" to make it numerical will hurt the performance.  Prefer to do it within encode_json (), which is implemented in C.

Comment: Another point, if I use "JSON" instead of "JSON::XS" module, the script will be the same (except for the module name change), there is a big performance difference. encode_json() on $a for 100,000 times with "JSON" module took 2.00seconds,  with "JSON::XS", it took 0.048sec.

Comment: How flat is the data structure? If it's flat you could modify them in place easily, if it's not flat it's a little more work but still doable. There is nothing inside the module that allows you to do it on the fly, so it has to be done on the Perl side.

Comment: If it is a flat hash of simple strings and integers, `for (values %$a) { $_ += 0 if /^\d+$/ }` should do it

Comment: @snoopy, thanks for the code snippet, the structure has multiple levels.

Comment: @Leeft, agree with you.  It would be a good feature request to modify the JSON::XS so that encoding can take some customerization.

Comment: Beware of /^\d+$/, this can match unicode digits as well. That is probably not desirable. Also, it doesn't catch all valid numbers like floats and negative numbers, things like that.

Comment: I've updated the answer (has to approved by moderators still, afaik) with a bit of code that does what you need it to do. I'm not sure I agree JSON should be modified to do this though, it would add a lot of overhead for everyone using it. Also, regarding JSON::XS not being used automatically, are you on an ancient version of the modules?

Comment: @codingFun: Why do you say *"using the trick of adding "0" to make it numerical will hurt the performance"*? I doubt if you would be able to measure the difference. Please don't dismiss workable solutions on the basis of a guess.

Comment: @Borodin, my part of the code needs to handle tens of thousands of hashes per second, each hash has hundreds fields in different levels. If I have to traverse each field in each hash, it may take too much CPU cycle.  Sorry that I didn't give enough info on the background. Thanks Snoopy Leeft for the sample codes. Wish there is a C function that takes the hash and output the encoded string.

Comment: At "tens of thousands of hashes per second" you have less than a millisecond to process each and that requires taking a serious amount of shortcuts. You're entering an entirely different problem area, and it would be far easier to not bother removing the quotes as one of the first shortcuts. Still, tens of thousands per second, I have a hard time imagining a valid use case for that.

Comment: @Leeft, agree that it's a different problem area. I tested the speed encode_json() from JSON::XS, it can do the encoding in a few us. So I am within the design goal. To be frank, tens of thousands of processing/sec is the worst case, but performance is indeed a concern. Thanks for all the helps. Seems that I need to use C to do the encoding.

Comment: Have you tested that with actual data? A "few microseconds" sounds highly unlikely, and that probably entirely ignores the overhead of things like transferring the actual data.